# How do I find the smallest combination of 2 numbers to get closest to another number

Tags: algorithm, math

I have two numbers: 6 & 10

I want to use a combination of these 2 numbers to get as close as possible to another number.

For example, to get to 9 I need 1 six with 3 remaining.
Other examples:

```
6: [6]
10: [10]
12: [6, 6]
18: [6, 6, 6]
20: [10, 10]
24: [6, 6, 6, 6]
26: [10, 10, 6]
28: [10, 6, 6, 6]
30: [10, 10, 10]
32: [10, 10, 6, 6]
```

I need an algorithm that can find the smallest number of combinations for any given number, taking preference for a combination with the smallest remainder. ie

```
38: [10, 10, 10, 6] - 2 remaining
38: [10, 10, 6, 6, 6] - no remainder, so preferred result
```

I hope I've explained this clearly, let me know if I need to clarify.

UPDATE:
To clarify, this is a real-world problem dealing with physical goods. The numbers 6 & 10 correspond to package cartons that contain multiples of a product in either 6 or 10 quantities.  We accept orders for these products in any amount, and want to calculate the smallest number of cartons that can make up the order, and then add the remainder as individual qtys.

A customer may want to order a qty of 39, so I need to know the smallest number of 6/10 qty cartons to make up the order, with the smallest number of remainders being the priority.

A customer may also order qtys of 1,2,3,4,5,6..... up to a max of about 300.

Comment: For your example with target number `9`, it appears that `10` should actually be the closest number instead of `6`. Are you really looking for the closest number or "the closest number that is less than or equal to the target number" ?

Comment: Is it allowed to take negative counts? For example to get 4 you would take 1 times 10 and -1 times 6.

Comment: This is a mathematical question, not a programming question.

Comment: You might want to read a little about dynamic programming.

Comment: assuming you have to stay below the target and you can only use addition this is an instance of the 'knapsack problem', look for that in the literature ...

Comment: see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem under solving. your's is an unbounded knapsack problem.

Comment: I've added clarification to my original question to answer these comments.

Comment: @GregorOphey this isn't really knapsack. One needs to find positive solutions to a linear diophantine equation ax+by=c. There's nothing NP-hard about it.

Comment: @n.m. Interesting. Thanks. I looked into it. Whereas ax + by = c has solution (x=-1, y=2) for a=10, b=6 and c=2 (=gcd(10,6)), there does not seem to be a positive solution. Using (x+k(b/c), y-(a/c))  I iterated k through the positive and negative integers for a bit and  could not find a positive solution.

Comment: @n.m. here https://eval.in/957955 is the code I used ...

Comment: @n.m. After going for a run in the snow (which was kind of a clean slate experience) it came to me that ax+by=gcd(a,b) never can have a solution where x > 0 and y > 0 since gcd(a,b) <= a and gcd(a,b) <= b. So considering everything there is no positive solution for a diophantine equation either, which puts me firmly back into knapsack land ...

Comment: @GregorOphey If there's no solution, there's no solution regardless of the method.

Comment: @n.m. of course there is a solution, since it is an optimization problem ... however solving the diophantine equation is the wrong method.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want the factorization of n in factors of a and b, then you just need to factorize the two possible ways and check which one gives you the minimal remainder.

So, you can something like this:

```
def factorize(a, b, n):
   return n/a, (n%a)/b, (n%a)%b

def factorize_min(a, b, n):
   na1, nb1, r1 = factorize(a, b, n)
   nb2, na2, r2 = factorize(b, a, n)
   return (na1, nb1) if r1 < r2 else (na2, nb2)

def factorize_min_list(a, b, n):
   na, nb = factorize_min(a, b, n)
   return [a]*na + [b]*nb
```

And use it like this:

```
for n in (6,10,12,18,20,24,26,28,30,32):
    print factorize_min_list(6, 10, n)
```

This would give you:

```
[6]
[10]
[6, 6]
[6, 6, 6]
[10, 10]
[6, 6, 6, 6]
[6, 10, 10]
[6, 10, 10]
[10, 10, 10]
[10, 10, 10]
```

Comment: I added clarification to my original question, so this does not work.  Testing 43 gives me 7 cartons of 6, but the smallest configuration is actually 3 cartons of 10 and 2 cartons of 6, with one remainder.  ie, 5 total cartons

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) that might be effectively solved using dynamic programming. Note that if needed sum cannot be produced exactly (like 9 in your example) - check lower neighbor cells of the DP table.

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less the coin problem. Above the Frobenius number all values can be built. Here we have 6 and 10 which aren't coprime. So we can divide by the greatest common divisor (2) to get 3 and 5 which are coprime. Then we get the Frobenius number 3*5 - 5 - 3 = 7. This means all even values > 14 can be built using 6 and 10 coins. The values are so few, that you could just make a list:

1. 3 (% 3 = 0), coins (1, 0)
2. 5 (% 3 = 2), coins (0, 1)
3. 6 (% 3 = 0), coins (2, 0)
4. 8 (% 3 = 2), coins (1, 1)
5. 9 (% 3 = 0), coins (3, 0)
6. 10 (% 3 = 1), coins (0, 2)

So the algorithm would be as follows:

1. divide input by 2
2. if it is smaller than 11 return the closest of the 6 values in the list
3. otherwise do input % 3, take corresponding configuration (8, 9 or 10), subtract it from input, divide by 3 and add the result to the 3 (i.e. 6) coins

Example for 32 (or 33):

1. 32 / 2 = 16
2. 16 >= 11
3. 16 % 3 = 1, we take 10 (0, 2), (16 - 10) / 3 = 2, add it to 3 coins => (2, 2)
4. check: 2 * 6 + 2 * 10 = 32

Answer (score 0):

The following is a C version of solving your problem with dynamic programming.
After you compile it you can run it with the total number of items as parameter
It will output the package sizes 10 and 6 separated by tabs
followed by their sum.
I took the algorithm from the german wikipedia page on the knapsack problem
https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rucksackproblem

It is quoted in the  comment at the beginning:

```
/*
U = { 10, 6 } n = 2
w = { 10, 6 }
v = {  2, 1 }

Eingabe: U, B, w, v wie oben beschrieben
  R := [1…(n+1), 0…B]-Matrix, mit Einträgen 0
  FOR i = n … 1
    FOR j = 1 … B
      IF w(i) <= j
        R[i,j] := max( v(i) + R[i+1, j-w(i)], R[i+1,j]\
 )
      ELSE
        R[i,j] := R[i+1,j]
Ausgabe: R[1,B]
*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int n = 2;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int w[3] = { -1, 10, 6 };
  int v[3] = { -1, 10, 6 };
  int B = atoi(argv[1]);
  size_t sz = ((B+1)*3*sizeof(int));
  int* R = malloc(sz);
  memset(R, 0, sz);
  for(int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= B; j++) {
      int b = R[i+1,j];
      if(w[i] <= j) {
        // max( v(i) + R[i+1, j-w(i)], R[i+1,j] )
        int a = v[i] + R[i+1, j-w[i]];
        R[i,j] = a>b?a:b;
      } else {
        R[i,j] = b;
      }
    }
  }
  int k = R[1,B];
  while(R[1,k]>0){
    int j = R[1,k];;
    for(int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
      int t = R[1,k-w[i]];
      if(t == k - w[i]) {
        j = w[i];
      }
    }
    printf("%i\t",j);
    k = k-j;
  }
  printf("\n%i\n", R[1,B]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3818525 did you give this a try? Do you need any help compiling etc.? Let me know if it works for you ...